# Django 1.8 LookupError AUTH_USER_MODEL

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication, django-1.8

I'm using a custon user model as such in my app called `fowl`.
When I run `syncdb` or `makemigrations` or `migrate` I get a `LookupError`. Please help

In `settings.py` I have defined `AUTH_USER_MODEL` as `'fowl.User'`

**fowl/models.py**

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager
    from django.utils import timezone
    from django.core.mail import send_mail
    from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(email,
                                password=password,
                                )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    Custom user class.
    """
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True, db_index=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    is_festival = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')
        abstract = True

    def get_full_name(self):
        """
        Returns the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
        """
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        """
        Returns the short name for the user.
        """
        return self.first_name

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Sends an email to this User.
        """
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)

    @property
    def is_festival(self):
        """Is the user a member of staff?"""
        return self.is_festival
```

When I run `syncdb` or `makemigrations` I get a `LookupError`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/Blu/projects/fowl/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/Blu/projects/fowl/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/Blu/projects/fowl/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/Blu/projects/fowl/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 440, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/Users/Blu/projects/fowl/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 478, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Users/Blu/projects/fowl/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Users/Blu/projects/fowl/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/checks.py", line 12, in check_user_model
    cls = apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
  File "/Users/Blu/projects/fowl/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 202, in get_model
    return self.get_app_config(app_label).get_model(model_name.lower())
  File "/Users/Blu/projects/fowl/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 162, in get_model
    "App '%s' doesn't have a '%s' model." % (self.label, model_name))
LookupError: App 'fowl' doesn't have a 'user' model.
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you run `manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Good question Eva, also, don't forget  `manage.py makemigrations`

Comment: @Eva611 yes. I still get the same error

Comment: @nir Thanks. I ran both and get the same `LookupError`. If I try to add them to admin.py I get a `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The model User is abstract, so it cannot be registered with admin.`

Comment: In your `class Meta` - you have `abstract=True`. Remove that, and then run the makemigrations

Comment: @karthikr OMG that was it. I've been racking my brains about such a silly overlooked error! Thanks! If you add this as an answer I will accept it!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your `User` class' `Meta`, you have set the `abstract=True` which is causing the issue. Remove it and then run `makemigrations`.

Also, note that you are repeating many fields already present in [`AbstractUser` class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py). You may eliminate them.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_festival = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    #The properties, methods, etc..
```