# Django 1.8 LookupError : Model not registered AUTH_USER_MODEL

Tags: python, django

Django 1.8 and Python 3.4

I'm using a custom User model called `UploaderClient` in my app called `authenticateclients` . When I run `check` or `makemigrations` or `migrate` I get a `LookupError: Model 'authenticateclients.UploaderClient' not registered.` error. Please help.

In settings.py I have defined `AUTH_USER_MODEL` as `authenticateclients.UploaderClient`

**authenticateclients/models.py**

```py
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

    # Create your models here.

   class UploaderClientManager(BaseUserManager):
       def create_user(self, accountname, password=None, **kwargs):
           if not accountname:
               raise ValueError('Users must have a valid accountname.')

           if not kwargs.get('email'):
               raise ValueError('Users must have a valid email.')

           if not kwargs.get('company_name'):
               raise ValueError('Users must have a valid company name.')

           account = self.model(
               accountname=self.normalize_accountname(accountname),email=kwargs.get('email'), company_name=kwargs.get('company_name')
           )

           account.set_password(password)
           account.save()

           return account

       def create_superuser(self, accountname, password, **kwargs):
           account = self.create_user(accountname, password, **kwargs)

           account.is_admin = True
           account.save()

           return account


   class UploaderClient(AbstractBaseUser):
       email = models.EmailField()
       accountname = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
       company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
       vuforiadb_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

       is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

       created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
       updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

       objects = UploaderClientManager()

       USERNAME_FIELD = 'accountname'
       REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email','company_name']

       def __unicode__(self):
           return self.accountname

       def get_company_name(self):
           return self.company_name

       def get_vuforiadb_name(self):
           return self.vuforiadb_name
```

**settings.py**

```py
"""
Django settings for ARPixelSite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

gettext = lambda s: s

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '@-$h5gh5%s$70hd=ii55it!+4@a*u8b(c8aqumqkx@*m8%v89l'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'djangocms_admin_style',  # for the admin skin. You **must** add 'djangocms_admin_style' in the list **before** 'django.contrib.admin'.
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'cms',  # django CMS itself
    'treebeard',  # utilities for implementing a tree
    'menus',  # helper for model independent hierarchical website navigation
    #'south',  # Only needed for Django < 1.7
    'sekizai',  # for javascript and css management
    'djangocms_file',
    'djangocms_flash',
    'djangocms_googlemap',
    'djangocms_inherit',
    'djangocms_picture',
    'djangocms_teaser',
    'djangocms_video',
    'djangocms_link',
    'djangocms_snippet',
    'rest_framework',
    'clientupload',
    'authenticateclients',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ARPixelSite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.core.context_processors.request',
                'django.core.context_processors.media',
                'django.core.context_processors.static',
                'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
                'cms.context_processors.cms_settings',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ARPixelSite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'ARPixelDB',
        'USER': 'djangouser',
        'PASSWORD': 'djangouser',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )
}

"""
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # The docs say it should be absolute path: BASE_DIR is precisely one.
    # Life is wonderful!
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"),
)
"""

CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ('template_1.html', 'Template One'),
    ('template_2.html', 'Template Two'),
)

LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', 'English'),
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

SITE_ID = 1

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

CMS_PAGE_MEDIA_PATH = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, "cms_page_media")

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authenticateclients.UploaderClient'
```

When I run `check` or `makemigrations` or `migrate` I get

```py
/home/dip7777/Desktop/ARPixelEnv/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py:321: RemovedInDjango19Warning: django.utils.importlib will be removed in Django 1.9.
  return f(*args, **kwds)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/dip7777/Desktop/ARPixelEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/dip7777/Desktop/ARPixelEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 328, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/dip7777/Desktop/ARPixelEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/dip7777/Desktop/ARPixelEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/dip7777/Desktop/ARPixelEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/dip7777/Desktop/ARPixelEnv/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/dip7777/Desktop/ARPixelEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cms/models/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .permissionmodels import *  # nopyflakes
  File "/home/dip7777/Desktop/ARPixelEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cms/models/permissionmodels.py", line 29, in <module>
    User = apps.get_registered_model(user_app_name, user_model_name)
  File "/home/dip7777/Desktop/ARPixelEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 266, in get_registered_model
    "Model '%s.%s' not registered." % (app_label, model_name))
LookupError: Model 'authenticateclients.UploaderClient' not registered.
```

So what I did is comment the line

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authenticateclients.UploaderClient'
```

and run `makemigrations` and `migrate`.
The migrations were applied.
Then on uncommenting the above line and trying `check` or `makemigrations` or `migrate` I'm still getting the same error.

Please help with the error.
If it is not possible to fix, can I proceed with my Project by commenting out the line or will the authentication not work if I leave out the line..

Comment: when you comment cms works because is get permission the cause of issue. And get persissions is on cms app.

Comment: What partially worked was commenting out `cms` - djangocms and other apps related to it in `INSTALLED_APPS`. I was able to `makemigrations` and `migrate`. But now if I uncomment `cms` and try `check` or `makemigrations` or `migrate`, I'm stuck with the same error.
So I'm not able to use the djangocms app.. 
Can somebody shed some light on how to use custom authentication and django-cms at the same time..

Comment: there's probably something in your code using cms stuff before the custom auth is registered, I usually stick to:  1) putting the custom User model in his app with only that class 2) move everything importing cms libraries out of model.py packages 3) import the custom auth before everything in INSTALLED_APPS and cms as last thing before local apps.

Answer (score 10):

For this specific problem, part of the problem is already pointed out by @danihp. You need to put the app with your custom model before "cms" in your INSTALLED_APPS.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = {
    'your_custom_app',
    '...',
    'cms',
}
```

Comment: Legend. Thank you!

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how and why you answer works ?

Comment: to add on to the answer above, I also had to make sure my imports of cms packages weren't listed until after my auth user model in my models.py

Answer (score 0):

Looking into your error stack trace it seems an issue getting permission:

> File "/home/dip7777/Desktop/ARPixelEnv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cms/models/permissionmodels.py", line 29, in 
>       User = apps.get_registered_model(user_app_name, user_model_name)

django docs [Customizing authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/) explains that:

> If you don’t include the PermissionsMixin, you must ensure you don’t invoke the permissions methods on ModelBackend. ModelBackend assumes that certain fields are available on your user model. If your User model doesn’t provide those fields, you will receive database errors when you check permissions.

Then, for your scenario, it seems an easy way to avoid error is to inherit from [PermissionsMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-permissions).

> This is an abstract model you can include in the class hierarchy for your User model, giving you all the methods and database fields necessary to support Django’s permission model.

For your code:

```
class UploaderClient(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
```

Comment: This didnt work.. I even tried the following : 1) Change my `authenticateclients/models.py ` to the model from `fowl/models.py` from this question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30270381/django-1-8-lookuperror-auth-user-model` . Then I changed `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authenticateclients.User'`. I still get the same model not registered error.

Comment: Thanks for answering.. I will try the above.. But if you could shed some light on my answer, it would be really helpful.. The issue might lie there..

Answer (score 0):

This question is the first result for `LookupError: Model '' not registered.`, so I'm adding this here:

For those who were installing some applications in a development environment with a sqlite3 db, you can simply delete the default `project.db` file (if you don't have anything to lose).